# How to check if an object is already exist in list of object in Python?

Tags: python, list, object

I have a list of objects (`ls`) that contains some objects of the same class:

```
>>print(f"list: {ls}, {type(ls}")
list: [<__main__.Puzzle object at 0x000001C061BBBB20>, <__main__.Puzzle object at 0x000001C061BBB880>, <__main__.Puzzle object at 0x000001C061BBB220>, <__main__.Puzzle object at 0x000001C061BBB160>], <class 'list'>
```

I want to check if a particular object (`obj`) is already in the list:

```
>>print(f"object: {obj}, {type(obj}")
object: <__main__.Puzzle object at 0x000001C061BBBB20>, <class '__main__.Puzzle'>
```

I have tried this:

```
if obj not in ls:
    ls.append(obj)
    print("Adding succeed")
else:
    print("Already exist")
```

but it returns an error message: `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`. Why does this occur?. The `obj` is a single value and `ls` is a list

Comment: That's a numpy error. So you have a numpy array, not a list.

Comment: it looks like you don't have `list` but `numpy.array`

Comment: Can `obj` sometimes be a numpy array, rather than an instance of your `Puzzle` class? Or is `Puzzle` a subclass of a numpy type? That error comes from calling `bool` on an array, probably one that comes from `__eq__` being called on a numpy array somewhere. The `in` operator compares `obj` with entries in the list, so that's likely the cause of the issue.

Comment: Yeah, I shouldn't have implemented `__eq__` in the class method. Thanks